# ValueError: Input tensors to a Model must come from `keras.layers.Input` missing metadata - trying to add lambda layer to ResNet in keras tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, metadata, tensor, aws-lambda-layers

I have a ResNet model that works for me. I am trying to add a couple of lambda layers to the front of it.  It is complaining with the following error:

"ValueError: Input tensors to a Model must come from `keras.layers.Input`. Received: Tensor("Shape:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32) (missing previous layer metadata)."

and I am not sure what this means or how to fix it.

I added code to the following two blocks for the lambda layers, which caused the problem. I know that I can do a numpy FFT prior to the ResNet.  Have done this previously, but am working toward having the FFT layer as the front layer of the ResNet with fixed coefficients. If there is some other way of accomplishing this, like creating another network that has the FFT lambda layer and making it sequential with the ResNet, such that error can be backpropagated through both networks, that would be ok.

The main goal is to have the FFT functionality in front of the ResNet layers and be able to backpropagate the error of the ResNet classifier to before the FFT layer in the easiest/best way.

```
def resnode(x_in,filter_count,kernel_size=3,downsample=False):
    x = x_in
    x = keras_contrib.layers.InstanceNormalization()(x)
    x = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda v: tf.spectral.fft(tf.cast(v,tf.complex64)))(x) 
    x = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda v: tf.abs(tf.cast(v,tf.complex64)))(x)    
    x = keras.layers.ReLU()(x)
    x = keras.layers.Conv1D(filter_count,kernel_size,padding='same')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
    x = keras_contrib.layers.InstanceNormalization()(x)
    x = keras.layers.ReLU()(x)
    x = keras.layers.Conv1D(filter_count,kernel_size,padding='same')(x)

    if downsample:
        x_in = keras.layers.AveragePooling1D()(x_in)
        x = keras.layers.AveragePooling1D()(x)

if x_in.shape[-1] != x.shape[-1]:
    print('convolving x_in',x_in.shape)
    x_in = keras.layers.Conv1D(filter_count,1,padding='same')(x_in)
    print('Newshape x_in',x_in.shape)
    
x = keras.layers.Add()([x_in,x])

return x

def createresnet(outputs=4):  
    n_features = N    
    x_input = keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,1))

    x_input = tf.shape(tf.squeeze(x_input))
    x = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda v: tf.spectral.fft(tf.cast(v,tf.complex64)))(x_input) # 
    x = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda v: tf.abs(tf.cast(v,tf.complex64)))(x)
    x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)
    x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    x = tf.expand_dims(x, axis=2)

    filter_size = 32 # 
    x = resnode(x,filter_size,kernel_size=7)  # FFT layer

    filter_size = 32
    x = resnode(x,filter_size,kernel_size=5,downsample=True)
    filter_size = 64
    x = resnode(x,filter_size,kernel_size=5,downsample=True)
    x = resnode(x,filter_size,kernel_size=5,downsample=True)
    filter_size = 128
    x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)
    x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)
    filter_size = 128
    x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)
    x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)
    filter_size = 128
    x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)
    x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)
    filter_size = 128
    x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)
    x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)
    filter_size = 64
    x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)

    if False:
        filter_size = 64
        x = resnode(x,filter_size)
        x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)
        filter_size = 64
        x = resnode(x,filter_size)
        x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)
        filter_size = 128
        x = resnode(x,filter_size)
        x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)
        filter_size = 128
        x = resnode(x,filter_size)
        x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)
        filter_size = 128
        x = resnode(x,filter_size)
        x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)
        filter_size = 128
        x = resnode(x,filter_size)
        x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)

    filter_size = outputs
    x = resnode(x,filter_size,downsample=True)
    x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
    x = keras.layers.Activation('softmax')(x)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=x_input,outputs=x)
    print(model.layers[0].output)
    print(model.layers[1].output)    

    return model
```

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: The problem lies in: `tf.shape(tf.squeeze(x_input))`. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: The squeeze was supposed to reduce dimensionality for the lambda fft layer. It works when I isolate that layer.  You can see that the squeeze solves the dimensionality problem.  However, I guess you and others are implying that this is the cause of the currently presented problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a @Frightera in the comments said, squeeze() removes all dimensions of size 1. You might be looking for flatten() which would reduce your channels into a 1D tensor for the fft() which applies 1D Fourier transform.

```
x_input = tf.flatten(x_input)
x = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda v: tf.spectral.fft(tf.cast(v,tf.complex64)))(x_input)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It might work on a more recent version of tensorflow.  My current version is 1.12.0.  It says that module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'flatten'. I will check for options in this area.  Thanks again.  If you have any other suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: You’ll want to likely add a flatten layer after the input layer. 


`x_input = Flatten()(x_input)`

Comment: @GS the problem is not squeeze, is tf.shape, and you did not reply to what is this line of code supposed to do?

Comment: The comment on the question does not say what you said it says :)

Comment: Just trying with the tf.shape and and squeeze to manipulate dimensionality to get it to work with the lambda fft layer and to resolve the dimensionality errors when sending it on down the line in the neural network.  I will try to figure out a better solution.  I guess it has been suggested that a flatten layer might work?  I am going to check that suggestion, but if anyone has any other ideas, please feel free to send them.  Thanks to everyone contributing to help.

Comment: Apologies @Dr.Snoopy you're right. I think what Snoopy is getting at is that if squeeze is returning the correct dimensions which you're likely validating with tf.shape(), then you don't need this call. 

Your error is caused because your lamda layer is receiving the shape tensor instead of the result of the squeeze().